# create a chat bot using UCWA 2.0

Tags: c#, skype, ucwa

I have created chat application using UCWA 2.0. Now i have a requirement where i need to create a chatbot that will use UCWA 2.0. I have to host the application on a window service. This application needs to read incoming messages to a specific ID and it will send message to available support engineers to resolve the users query.

I can not use bot framework as we are not meeting prerequisites. I have to achieve this using UCWA. No documentations are available for this. It will be helpful if someone can help with an example to achive this.